# How to run Hausman Test for endogeneity on during regression in Python using StatsModels?

Tags: python, regression, data-science, statsmodels

How can I run a Hausman test for endogeneity in Python using StatsModels?

Comment: Use linearmodels: https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/examples/advanced-examples.html?highlight=hausman#Testing-endogeneity

Comment: Can you please link a tutorial that makes it a little easier to understand 2SLS and the Wu-Hausman test?